# NodeJS - Sorting Like Rock Paper Scissors - Dynamic Number Of Players

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a game that has a sort of rock paper scissors system, only more complicated, using "values" such as 3 rock beats 2 rock, where one player can choose the amount of rocks he wants to use in one turn. This game can/has to handle more than 2 players, but 2 players is also possible. I was only able to do that with values, using this code:

```
        array.push({ "player": player, "score": parseInt(cardInformation.value), "Seat": i, element: cardInformation.element});

        array.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.score - a.score;
        });

        var rank = 1;
        var lastWinner = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && array[i].score < array[i - 1].score) {
                rank++;
            }
            array[i].rank = rank;
            array[i].winStatus = loss;
            if(rank == 1) {
                if(lastWinner != -1) {
                    array[lastWinner].winStatus = tie;
                    array[i].winStatus = tie;
                } else 
                    array[i].winStatus = win;
                lastWinner = i;
            }
        }
```

I've looked all over for a system like rock paper scissors but all I could find was for 2 players and I'm unsure how to make it more. Please help me if you have the time.

Comment: You will have to describe a bit more if there is something like **timed turns** and other game logic ( like detecting the total number of players or something similar...) is it in real time, all at the same time, every **x** seconds? we need more info to help you :P

Comment: @EMX thanks for responding! The game is dynamic, it can handle alot of users, but it can also handle 2. 2 is a minimum. There is no timed turns, but to get the number of total players playing I just have to array.length. It's real time, they all pick at the same time.

Comment: I suppose you are using `socket.io` also, right?

Comment: No, what I have is a server for a flash client, not that this has anything to do with this.

Comment: @EMX ^ Forgot to tag you

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
const TURN_INTERVAL = 10//seconds
const GAME_STATE = {
  status:1, // 1:player action is allowed / 0:player action is frozen
  turnData:{ // temp storage for playerIDs grouped by value chosen
    1:[], //paper
    2:[], //scissors
    3:[]  //rock
  },
  versus:{ //what kills what
    1:3,
    2:1,
    3:2
  }
}

function GlobalTurn(){
  console.log('[Round]','started')
  GAME_STATE.status = 0; // players must wait for turn end response
  for(var i=1; i<4;i++){ // notify each group of how many they killed
   var thisGroupKills = GAME_STATE.versus[i]; //which is the weak group against this one
   var totalKilled = GAME_STATE.turnData[thisGroupKills].length //how much this group has killed
   console.log('group',i,'killed a total of',totalKilled) //send to clients instead
   /* Here you can iterate over each playerID if you need to :
   for(var j=0; j<GAME_STATE.turnData[i].length){
   console.log('player',GAME_STATE.turnData[i],'killed a total of',totalKilled)
   }
   */
  }
  EndTurn() 
}

function EndTurn(){
  console.log('Next round will start in',TURN_INTERVAL,'seconds')
  GAME_STATE.turnData = {1:[],2:[],3:[]} //reset for next round
  GAME_STATE.status = 1; // players can send actions (their pick)
  setTimeout(GlobalTurn,TURN_INTERVAL*1000); //prepare next round calculator
}
```